# Getting notified of new answers

Tags: discussion

I reviewed [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114311/33055) where the OP answered their own Q. And although the actual actions were not clear to me they might be to someone else¹.

What I noticed is that just 5 days ago someone commented on the original question about having the same problem. But AFAIK that person never gets notified of the now existing answer.

[Starring as favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/186664) does not seem to do that (yet)². Regularly having to come back as an interested party, while there might not even be a new answer is something few people would do on a regular basis. And expecting the OP or the person providing the answer to go over the comments specifying "I have that problem to" does not really seem a reasonable solution either, and I would hate to see comments like this spawn because it is the only way (to hope for) a notification.

Apart from actually commenting on the comment and @usernaming the commenter and hoping someone will comment back once there is an answer, is there currently a way for him/her to get an automated notification about new answers on questions that the are interested in?

¹ <sub>I did ask for more details.</sub>
² <sub>And from the zero favored this Q count I can see the commenter did not use that option anyway.</sub>

Comment: I thought that was what "favoriting" was supposed to do. As you say though, ["not yet"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work).